# Modify XFS filesystem creation parameters during kickstart installation

Tags: filesystems, centos6, xfs, kickstart, rhel6

I'm streamlining the kickstart process for a series of EL6.2 (RHEL, CentOS, SL, etc.) systems. I'd prefer to use XFS over ext4 for the growth/data partition. However, I'd like some control over the options passed to `mkfs.xfs` for the creation of the partition. I'd typically create this partition after the server was built, so that I'd have this control. But this should really be automated.

When creating a manual XFS partition of 400GB, I'd usually use a command string like:

`mkfs.xfs -f -L /data -d agcount=100 -l size=128m,version=2 /dev/cciss/c0d1p0`

With `/etc/fstab` mount options like:

`LABEL=/data /data                    xfs     noatime,logbufs=8,logbsize=256k,nobarrier 1 2`

---

How can I get something similar built into the anaconda kickstart installation process without resorting to placing it in %post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your options for creating filesystems are limited to those described in [the kickstart documentation](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html) (in particular, the `part`, `logvol`, and `raid` commands).  The assumption there is generally that you're happy with the default options when creating filesystems.  If you need anything fancier, you'll need to use the `%pre` or `%post` section to call mkfs.xfs directly.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit ugly, especially if specific formatting options are needed.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to specify non-default mkfs options during Kickstart is to use the `--fsprofile` flag to the `part` command.  Unfortunately, this requires that the filesystem-specific mkfs have a "usage type" feature.  With `mke2fs`, this is a `-T` flag that references `/etc/mke2fs.conf`.  For XFS, uhhhh …

But maybe that can point you in the right direction.

Oh, and `--fsoptions` allows you to specify mount options.