# Cannot install centos 6.4 with XFS

Tags: centos, filesystems, installation, xfs

I would like install centos 6.4 and use XFS as filesystem for some partitions in my configuration. But Anaconda don't propose XFS in the filesystem choice. Then I try to install in text mode but in this case I don't succeed to personalise my partition table.  How can I use XFS for certain partitions, such as the one I plan to mount at `/var`?

Comment: Do you want the entire system to be on XFS? Or do you just want part of the drive to be XFS?

Comment: I just want some partition in XFS, like `/var`

Answer (score 2):

Currently basic RedHat Enterprise Linux 6/CentOS 6 doesn't support XFS as root filesystem. There is a addon-package for RHEL 6 to support it as non-root partition, after installation.

It is best not to use XFS with RHEL/CentOS 6 and wait for CentOS 7 (2014) or if you really have to use XFS, you can try Fedora for up-to-date XFS support.

Comment: atleast CentOS 6.4 has XFS module and utilities for filesystem in 64-bit environment so it available as other non-root partitions, just create partitions and use mkfs.xfs from xfsprogs -package to format the partition as XFS. Note: it is 64b only.

Comment: It's available without addon-package for Centos.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 6.4 32-bit doesn't include XFS support, but it is included in the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using the installer to create your XFS partitions. [You can't get the right types of XFS optimizations or mkfs.xfs options](https://serverfault.com/questions/357057/modify-xfs-filesystem-creation-parameters-during-kickstart-installation), and it's more flexible to run this post-installation.

Honestly, ext4 is fine for this. I only use XFS on data partitions. If you use a kickstart build, you can do this, though:

```
part /boot --fstype=ext4 --size=300
part / --fstype=ext4 --asprimary --size=20480
part /usr --fstype=ext4 --asprimary --size=12288    
part swap --size=8192
part /var --fstype=xfs --size=6144
part /tmp --fstype=ext4 --size=2048
```

Comment: Anaconda will absolutely [refuse to create a root partition as XFS](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QLH2k.png). Though this will be supported (and the default) in EL7.

Comment: [The OP asked for `/var`.](http://serverfault.com/questions/527900/cannot-install-centos-6-4-with-xfs/531867?noredirect=1#comment603241_527900)

Comment: Bah, comments. Who reads those?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that if you'll prepare partition before installation i.e. use livecd with xfs support like [partedmagic](http://partedmagic.com/) to do that. But anyway, **it won't give you any advantage**. Personalize your partition table/reformat/change partition and /var after installation.

-

[QA: Can XFS be used for a root filesystem?](http://xfs.org/index.php/XFS_FAQ#Q:_Can_XFS_be_used_for_a_root_filesystem.3F)

-

Q: Does Centos support it without additional package?

A: Yes for 64-bit Centos, it includes XFS support without additional package, additional package provides only tools for XFS (fsck, mkfs, debug etc):

```
[root@main ~]# rpm -ql kernel|grep xfs
/lib/modules/2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64/kernel/fs/xfs
/lib/modules/2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64/kernel/fs/xfs/xfs.ko
[root@main ~]# cat /etc/centos-release 
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```